# How to find max element of a doubly linked list?

Tags: c++, binary-tree, doubly-linked-list

After reading the data from a file in a double-linked list I must determine the maximum of the this data. This topic is new to me so I need some help. This is what i have :

```
struct node {
  int info;
  node *next, *back;
};
node *cap = NULL;
node *first, *last, *c, *q;
```

Comment: Step 1: try to write some code that simply traverses the list.  Step 2: figure out how extend what you wrote in step 1 to find the max.

Comment: @NPE can i do as in case of an array , set max. elem,. the first "info" , and after that compare this with all "next" elements ?

Comment: @Cristian of course, you can! But you need to compare not with "next" elements, but with their values (that means with their "info"s). And you need to check haven't you reached the end of the list?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list , https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the list and store the max like this:

```
node *max = first;
while (first) {
    if (max->info < first->info)
        max = first;
    first = first->next;
}
```

This assumes that `next` is null pointer when the element is the last one.

Answer (score -1):

What are *c and *q for?

Also, if you can already traverse the list, just create a max node and update it while traversing